# Automatic outlining (collapsible sections) does not start for .ASPX files in Visual Studio 2010 SP1

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

In Visual Studio 2010 SP1, automatic outlining is not enabled for ASPX files when I open them.  For each file opened, I need to click Edit / Outlining / Start automatic outlining, which is extremely annoying.  This step is not necessary when code-only (non-ASPX) files are opened.

I use a few extensions, all of them from MS, including Power Tools, the JavaScript tools, etc., and I thought that maybe they were causing the problem, so I disabled all of them and restarted VS, but the problem still exists.

I did not have this problem with VS2010 (no SP) on Win XP Pro, which I used for about 18 months, but I recently did a clean install of Win 7 x64, VS2010, and VS2010 SP1, and now I have this issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: Anyone?  I must not be the only person with this problem!

Comment: I have upgraded to SP1 and I have the same problem, extremely annoying indeed. I have assigned a keyboard shortcut to it (Ctrl+`) but that's not good enough.

Comment: This is just beyond aggravating. None of the suggestions in any of the answers solved the problem for me. The registry key just keeps getting reset to -1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted the same question at the MS forums, and was told to do the following, which I have not yet had time to try, but I thought I would add it here for now:

> Please try to create two new project (one is the same type project as
>   your previous project, one is another type project.) see whether this
>   issue still exists.
>
> If this issue still exists, you can try the following solutions:
>
> 1. If we reboot the operating system to safe mode, do we have the
>      problem? This can help to isolate whether any other applications are
>      interfering with Visual Studio. Note that some features (like IIS) are
>      not available under safe mode. Please check whether this can apply or
>      not. In addition to safe mode, we can also suggest “clean boot”:
>      http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310353 .
>
>    1. If we create a new user account, do we have the problem? This can
>         help to isolate user profile corruption related causes.
>    2. If we use “devenv.exe /resetsettings”, does it solve the problem?
>         It restores Visual Studio default settings.
>    3. If the problem remains, we can use Visual Studio Setup Wizard (via
>         Control Panel) to repair Visual Studio. It can restore the Visual
>         Studio Installation into its original state.

The forum thread is [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vseditor/thread/8e42b539-d2a5-48f8-a718-a97f64b3a7f0/).

I will provide my results if I make progress.

Comment: Just tried devenv.exe /resetsettings, and it did not fix the problem.  Don't have time for a full repair/reinstall right now.

Comment: That response from MS just seems to be a generic response rather than specific to this problem. I'm surprised they didn't tell you to turn your PC off and on again :-)

Answer (score 16):

This worked for me:

In the registry, look here:

**HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\HTML Editor**

for a value named **OutlineHTMLOnFileOpen**. Mine was set to 0, change it to 1. Make sure you do this while VS is closed, as it saves this value out on exit and will change it back.

Comment: I was so excited to try this, but it did not work for me.  Note that on my PC, the value for this key was -1, and it returns to that on close.

Comment: I tried this directly after running devenv.exe /resetsettings and it appears to have worked, thanks :)

Comment: @Brian,  between your experience and the answer you got in the MS forums, it must be some *twisted* logic that determines whether outlining is shown for aspx files or not. Too bad this didn't help, the frustration is over the top, and I only had to deal with it for about a week.

Comment: Thank you for all of the suggestions.  I might try Lightweight's protocol of changing the key right after a reset, when I have time.  Will check back with my results.

Comment: This didn't work for me. I also reset my settings back to C# Dev Environment defaults....still no luck. On a new project if I set it to 1 before I open VS it seems to work but when I close and reopen it goes back to -1

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me. For VS2012, the key will be HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\HTML Editor everything else remains the same.

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue and it was driving me crazy all week!!

**Finally managed to fix it really easy:**

Make sure the registry value for OutlineHTMLOnFileOpen is set to: **-1**

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\HTML Editor

OutlineHTMLOnFileOpen = -1
```

Open VS then open an aspx file.

Press CTRL M then M again while keeping the CTRL key depressed.

```
Press Ctrl+ M M
```

Wait a few moments and the automatic outlining engine will start.

Restart VS and it should auto kick in again when you open a file.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and went through and disabled my extensions. Once I disabled the Javascript Addins from Microsoft (That give the outlining and brace matching), I found I was able to change the registry setting and it didn't set change back. I'm going to reinstal the addin to see if it was the actual cause.

Comment: Interesting possibility... please let us know.

Comment: Well I've not had time to reinstall the addin, but I have moved on to VS2012, and my Automatic Outlining was disabled today. I do have the Microsoft Web Developer Tools extension installed.

Answer (score 0):

Using Ctrl + M should toggle this if you're focused on the file having trouble. I had the same problem until I realized had been accidentally using the hot keys to turn this on and off.

Comment: Doesn't work for me.  Are you referring to the Ctrl+M, Ctrl+M shortcut for expand/collapse?

Comment: Ctrl+M, Ctrl+M worked for me - in my experience around 80% of the time aspx files open with outlining on and working fine. Sometimes closing and opening the file works for me as well - weird.

Comment: Also occasionally it seems to take a minute or so for the outlining to appear from opening the file.