# Visual Studio 2010 - sometimes markup language doesn't have collapsibility. How to correct?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have pages in VS2010 (C#) which when I open the markup language (aspx), once in awhile the text can't be collapsed.

I frequently collapse by tags when I need to add new sections of markup.

Has anyone else experienced this?  Does anyone know a solution?

Closing and reopening the page doesn't always work.
Switching to design mode and back doesn't seem to always work either.

[I am using the most recent service pack].

Answer (score 0):

Just a VS2010 quirk? It does it to me sometimes too, and we're definitely not the only ones - [Automatic outlining (collapsible sections) does not start for .ASPX files in Visual Studio 2010 SP1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7113301/automatic-outlining-collapsible-sections-does-not-start-for-aspx-files-in-vis)