# Automatic outlining (collapsible sections) does not start on file open for .ASPX files in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, outlining

For quite a few versions of Visual Studio Community 2022 (currently on 17.7.0), Automatic Outlining has not automatically started on file open.

It works fine for C# etc:
[image]

But, there is no such option for aspx files. I can only get outlining if I trigger is manually:
[image]

Is there a workaround for this to auto happen when I open an aspx files? For completeness's sake, this is what I want to show automatically on file open:
[image]

I have had this problem for many months, across different installs/fresh OS installs.

Comment: It's a very old Q/A and for a much earlier version of VS but does this help: [Automatic outlining (collapsible sections) does not start for .ASPX files in Visual Studio 2010 SP1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7113301/10871073)?

Comment: Unfortunately not :/